# How can i set/update Person Field(person/group field) via powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I have a column(it has a display name e.g John Shane) and I would like to use that to set/update an empty person field.
Why I need this is because this  list was migrated from sharepoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 and the only way moved it across was via an excel sheet.
I would like to achieve this using PowerShell.

Also if the user doesn't exist is there a way I can add the user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link is helpful for this stuff: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx

Comment: Thanks Robert. But the question is how can I get an email or username from a display name?
Cheers

Comment: No it isn't, not as it is formulated now

Comment: I think I figured it out. I will try and filter Get-SPUser by displayname and that should return the email. Will update soon